# Shading nodes disappeared in Blender

Tags: shaders

So i was following Blender Guru's Donut Tutorial and in Part 3, Level 2, when he opens the shading node editor, his node are there but when i open my shading editor, there are no nodes even if i have the preview. I also have the use nodes on in Composting[image]

Comment: From the image, it looks like you have a camera selected as a first object (yellow)and the mesh as secondary objects (orange). Cameras can't have shaders, you just need to deselect the camera.

Answer (score 3):

In the picture there you can see the *camera* is actually first object (the object it shows nodes for), for it is outlined yellow, and the donut mesh is  the secondary object, you can see it is orange. You may have accidentally selected the camera and only group selected the donut, like I tend to do often with my projects. Just try zooming in a little closer and selecting the donut again, and you should be able to see the donut's nodes.